# How do I correctly size a variable height TListViewItem when using LiveBindings?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio, tlistview

I have a `TListView` which I'm using the `OnUpdateObjects` event to size the height of the `TListViewItem` depending no how long a text field is in a DataSet (I'm using LiveBindings).  This works pretty good except when I add a new record, the height is initially the design time height of the `TListViewItem`.  When I add an additional item (which is sized incorrectly) the old record gets resized correctly (and so on for adding additional records).

I've based my code around the ListViewVariableHeightItems sample project.  The event code looks like the following

```
procedure TForm8.lvLogUpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  itemDetail: TListItemText;
  Text: string;
  AvailableWidth: Single;
  TextHeight : integer;
begin
  AvailableWidth := TListView(Sender).Width - TListView(Sender).ItemSpaces.Left
    - TListView(Sender).ItemSpaces.Right;

  // Find the text drawable which is used to calcualte item size.
  itemDetail := TListItemText(AItem.View.FindDrawable('txtDetail'));
  Text := itemDetail.Text;

  // Calculate item height based on text in the drawable
  TextHeight := GetTextHeight(itemDetail, AvailableWidth, Text);
  AItem.Height := round(itemDetail.PlaceOffset.Y + TextHeight);
  itemDetail.Height := TextHeight;
  itemDetail.Width := AvailableWidth;
end;
```

The `GetTextHeight` function is straight from the ListViewVariableHeightItems project and seems to work correctly.

I'm after suggestions as to how to get the initial sizing of the `TListViewItem` to reflect the length of text that `txtDetail` Drawable contains (or at least should contain from the dataset).

Answer (score 0):

I've only been able to find a rather lame solution to this, append an extra record to the dataset, then cancel it.  I'm happy to accept a better solution if anyone can provide one.